# Unable to Retrieve Supply Levels in Print Queue

Tags: macos, mac, cups, lexmark-printer

Retrieving the supply levels of my printer in the print queue application used to work fine but now I get an `Information Not Available` error. In the error logfile it says `Unable to query ink levels`.

[image: Mac OS X Print Queue]

Printer Model: Lexmark E323
Mac OS Version: 10.7.2 (11C74)

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/16969677#16969677

> One common workaround at the time was to modify the PPD for the printer so that the SNMP calls were not made. This is done by adding the line "*cupsSNMPSupplies: False" to the printers ppd file located in the /etc/cups/ppd. Note that you will need administrative privileges to perform this workaround.

Comment: Very interesting thread. I have to take a look and see if it can resolve my issue.

Comment: A nice workaround. When using a network printer that threw "The printer may be out of toner" everytime I printed something and had the printer queue dock icon hopping around adding `*cupsIPPSupplies: False` to the end of the ppd files in `/etc/cups/ppd` stopped the annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, and for a different printer (Canon MFC743), and on Ventura (13.5.1), but hopefully will help someone else looking for how to get Supply Levels to load on macOS.

Using the other answer and its mention of SNMP I went into the control panel for my printer and enabled SNMP V1, on the standard public community and it loads up now.

So, looks like behind the scenes it's making a standard SNMP call for the levels info, and you need SNMP enabled and accessible on your printer.